# Who were the firefighters in Muslim North Africa in the 18th/19th Century and how were they organized?

Tags: islam, political-history, north-africa

As we know that the Romans already had some forces for keeping their cities secured and safe: The *Vigiles* who were what we now may call police and firefighters together!

And as I failed to find some more information about it: I wonder how this was solved and organized later in the modern times. I'm looking for information on pre-colonial firefighting in Tunisia, Morocco and Algeria.

To focus on one vocational field: Who where the firefighters in Muslim countries and how were they organized, and what were their duties? And how modern were they especially as influences from modern Europe may come into account.

If a focus on location is needed then I would say northern Africa/Maghreb states, would be my focus (I'm aware that even those could be divided into independent countries/states and those who were ruled by Ottomans)!

*spoiler* 
I used the politics tag as I wasn't sure if it would be helpful to create an administration tag or something more relevant!

Comment: I see but there was something like a Nightwatch or watchman, so i hope at least to have answers from this corner! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchman_%28law_enforcement%29

Comment: @Bregalad There were certainly firefighters in 18th century "1st world countries". The Copenhagen Royal Fire Brigade was created in 1687, and the Nanking Water Dragon Bureau in the mid 1700s, for instance. I don't know the specifics for North Africa, but it seems prudent to not assume there wasn't any.@OP +1 but I think you should about the firefighters and police separately in two different questions. It seem to stand to reason that they would be different organisations.

Comment: @Semaphore You got a point, probably there were firefighters since long ago in large cities, but not in remote villages, where people would help themselves. Back then there was no individualism like there is today. Today if one's neighbour's house is on fire they'd just complaint it is a nuisance for the bad smelling and smoke instead of actually helping them. I never said I should assume there weren't any.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Another wild guess (that would have to be either proven true or false), I think the emergencies in general (whether it's fire or anything else) were handled by the army historically. That's is why there is also grades in the firefighters just like there is for the army.

Comment: @Bregalad i would agree and also assume that the army could always be at least a part of those forces!

Comment: Fire is endemic to large cities. For that reason alone, Cairo at least had to have some kind of institutionalized scheme for firefighting.